# Firebase wait until values are updated

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

I would like to send data to Firebase database and Wait until data are updated to do other action like $state.go or something else.

**How can I do that in a good way with Firebase and AngularJs ?**

This my part of code :

```
  var ref_achats_offres = firebase.database().ref('achats_offres');
  var key_achats_offres = ref_achats_offres.push().key;
  var ladate = moment().format();
  var accountId = $localStorage.accountId;
  var push_achats_offres = ref_achats_offres.child(key_achats_offres).set({
              cout: cout,
              ajout_le: ladate,
              active:true,
              accounts: accountId,
              id_offre : id_offre,
              unique_code: code
          });

 var ref_offres = firebase.database().ref('offres');
 ref_offres.child(id_offre).child('achats_offres').child(key_achats_offres).set(true);
 var ref_accounts = firebase.database().ref('accounts');
 ref_accounts.child(accountId).child('achats_offres').child(key_achats_offres).set(true);
          firebase.database().ref('accounts').child(accountId).child('credits').transaction(function(credits) {
            return credits - cout;
          });

          $scope.modal2.hide();
          Utils.message(Popup.checkIcon, Popup.achatOffreEffectue);
          $state.go('mes_achats');
```

Comment: I know nothing about Angular. However what you are looking for is a firebase "transaction": https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#save_data_as_transactions
The way the callback of the transaction is called is a bit complaxe but enable a very flexible usage, you should read the details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

Comment: Also see AngularFire's advice on best practices for routing (i.e. use `resolve`) [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers).

Comment: @Kato I don't understand what you're saying ! Did I do something wrong with my routes ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set()` and `transaction()` calls returns a Promise. When the write operation completes, the promise resolves and you can handle this by implementing `then()`.

If you want the two set operations to run in sequence and then navigate:

```
ref_accounts.child(accountId).child('achats_offres').child(key_achats_offres)
    .set(true)
    .then(function() {
        firebase.database().ref('accounts').child(accountId).child('credits')
            .transaction(function(credits) {
                return credits - cout;
            })
            .then(function() {
                $scope.modal2.hide();
                Utils.message(Popup.checkIcon, Popup.achatOffreEffectue);
                $state.go('mes_achats');
            });
    });
```

If you want them to run in parallel and both complete before you navigate:

```
var setPromise = ref_accounts.child(accountId).child('achats_offres').child(key_achats_offres).set(true);
var transactionPromise = firebase.database().ref('accounts').child(accountId).child('credits')
            .transaction(function(credits) {
                return credits - cout;
            });
Promise.all([setPromise, transactionPromise]).
       .then(function() {
           $scope.modal2.hide();
           Utils.message(Popup.checkIcon, Popup.achatOffreEffectue);
           $state.go('mes_achats');
       });
```

Comment: thank you ! The second way is exactly what I was looking for. It's an elegant way to do what I expected. Thank you again.